# Parallelizable MAC/hash value stored securely

Tags: hash, mac

Assume the following:

- $E: \{0, 1\}^k \times \{0, 1\}^b \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^b$ is a block cipher with a $k$-bit key size and a $b$-bit block size.
- $T$ is a $b$-bit authentication tag that is guaranteed to be untampered with (e.g., by being calculated abd stored by a trusted system).
- $X_i$ represents the $i$<sup>th</sup> of a string of data blocks that $T$ is calculated against.
- $X_i \in \{0, 1\}^b$.
- $K_1$ and $K_2$ are keys that both $k$ bits long.

If $T_i = E(K_1, X_i \oplus E(K_2, i))$ and $T = T_0 \oplus \ldots \oplus T_{n-1}$, then is $T$ secure as a MAC if it's stored by the party who wants to use it to verify some data? If so, can the calculation of $T_i$ be replaced by a difficult-to-reverse public function that takes $X_i$ and $i$ as input while still remaining secure?

I was driven to design this as an improvement on [Apple's anti-replay scheme for their Secure Enclave's memory](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/secure-enclave-sec59b0b31ff/web#:%7E:text=The%20nonce%20is%20used%20as,tree%20up%20to%20the%20SRAM.).

Comment: In above I think we can presume that $X_i$ is the specific block of plaintext. That's not indicated and I thought that you would use it to represent ciphertext, but no cipher is actually indicated to achieve confidentiality. Note that this is basically CTR followed by ECB mode encryption using a different key, after which the ciphertext is the XOR of all the calculated ECB blocks. That doesn't feel right to me, but I'll have a deeper look.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-onstrike It doesn't matter what $X_i$ is. It's just data stored to be authenticated at a later time, like upon accessing a byte in RAM. It's meant as an improvement upon Apple's replay protection scheme for the Secure Enclave's memory.

Comment: can you explain the difference with Apple replay protection scheme and why you think it's an improvement? You have linked to a very long document that you expect people to have the patience to read through.